# Starting Timer problem from Asynchronous Server Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, network-programming

I have got a Client/Server Application that using Asynchronous Socket.My problem is i cant start timer control on Client Side from Server side.I have got a method for sending data to client from server side and client got a method for handle this data and starts the timer.There is no problem at getting data and process it.But timer control is not working.**I have got a button on client side thats starting timer with same code.** So its working with a button on client side but not working if this command come from server.Whats the problem ??

Here is my codes ;

```
 void MessageSend(string msj)
    {

        foreach (Client _client in connectedCompList)
        {
//for sending data from server side to client side
            _client.clientSoket.Send(ConvertByteArray(msj)); 

        }

    }
private void btnStartExam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageSend("/t/" + "," + txtMinute.Text + "," + txtSecond.Text+",");
    }


 void MessageControl(string message)
    {

        if (message.Length < 1)
            return;

        switch (message.Substring(0, 3))
        {
            case "/e/":
                txtAdayNo.Text = "";
                txtVeri.Text = "";
                txtAdSoyad.Text = "";
                txtSinav.Text = "";
                break;
            case "/t/":
                // starting exam after separate min and sec.
                string[] time = message.Split(',');
                minute = Convert.ToInt32(time[1]);
                second = Convert.ToInt32(time[2]);
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Start();
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }

 private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // working with this event.
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the timer is a `Windows.Forms.Timer`, you'll need to call `Control.Invoke` to marshal the call that sets the timer properties and starts the timer back on the UI thread.

You should also do this for all of your text box and other UI elements.  I suspect this is your problem, since socket communication typically occurs on a ThreadPool thread and not on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: But i can control every windows forms control on client side Except Timer object.So there is no problem with other controls.Can you give me an example for me ?

Comment: @Ibrahim: Have you set a break point to make sure you're actually getting into that call?

Comment: Yeah. Its process codes but its not getting into Timer Tick event.

Comment: @Ibrahim: try changing it to:  `this.Invoke(new Action( () => { timer.Enabled = true; timer.Start(); }));`

Comment: i am using .NET Framework 2.0 so lambda not working. Is there .NET 2.0 Way ?

Comment: @Ibrahim: Yes - Make it a separate method, and use a delegate.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed my problem >> this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate() { 
                        timer.Enabled = true; timer.Start();
                    
                    }));